# WooCommerce - Hide related products if product has no categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am wondering if there is a way to hide the related product tab in the single product page only if the product has no categories set.

This is what I tried:

```
global $product; 

// Return the product categories
$categories = $product->get_categories( ', ', ' ' . _n( ' ', '  ', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', ' ' );

if(empty($categories)){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
    }
```

This was added to functions.php but it is not working. Anyone would have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, Try below code.

```
function remove_related_product()
{
    global $product; 

    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );

    if(empty($terms))
    {
         remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'remove_related_product',10);
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

This code is tested on WooCommerce 3+ and works